# C# Не обновляется значение свойства

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, property

Есть есть класс:

```
public class VertexArrayObject : DeviceResource
    {
        int verticies = 0;
        public int Verticies { get => verticies;}

        ...

        protected override void loadOnDevice()
        {
            if (verticies == 0) verticies = buffer_arrays[0].Count; // buffer_arrays[0].Count == 568

            ...

        }

    }
```

В другом классе для экземпляра первого класса выполняется следующий код:

```
 VertexArrayObject vertex_array;

 public MeshBlock(VertexArrayObject vertex_array, RenderingTecnique tecnique)
        {
            this.vertex_array = vertex_array;
            this.tecnique = tecnique;
        }

 ...

 public void DrawGeometry()
        {
            if (vertex_array.Verticies == 0) return;

            ...

        }
```

Проблема: Во втором классе `vertex_array.Verticies` всегда возвращает `0`, до того момента пока в этом месте не будет вызвана точка останова в отладчике и не раскрыта подробная информация о полях класса, в этот момент, подгружается правильное значение поля и при продолжение программы, всё работает правильно. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

При сборке в Release тоже не работает.

Классы находятся в одной dll библиотеке.
Версия Visual Studio: 2019

Update:

Проверил прямой доступ к переменной, та же проблема

Comment: Как я вижу, значение поля `verticies` меняется в методе `loadOnDevice`. Вероятно, проблема в том, что метод `loadOnDevice` нигде не вызывается. Ну или же предоставьте полный код, если этот метод всё же вызывается.

Comment: По хорошему нужно просто везде в сомнительных местах добавлять логирование. Если бы в начале метода loadOnDevice() было залогированы значения verticies и buffer_arrays[0].Count, вы бы знали, вызывается ли вообще этот метод, когда именно он вызывается, и чему равны эти значения. Но ещё я бы залогировал вызов конструктора этого класса. Чтобы понимать всю картину как и что происходит.

Comment: Проблема за пределами показанного кода. _Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?_ - с чем? С тем что ты присвоил значение в поле, а оно не присвоилось? Это технически невозможно. Вся концепция программирования развалится, если убрать 100% гарантию присваивания. Не надо верить в магию, надо отлаживать код.